# Getting authenticated user on redirect using Laravel API endpoints

Tags: php, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I am build API endpoints using Laravel 5.8 and handling API authentication using Passport. So here's the simple logic of the React app that will be consuming the API

1. Successful registration will redirect user to user dashboard
2. Successful login will redirect user to user dashboard
3. Dashboard displays user detailed information

I have set up the endpoints like this

```
Route::post('register', 'BaseController@register');

Route::post('login', 'BaseController@login);
```

BaseController looks like this right now

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname'  => 'required',
        'username'  => 'required|email',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['Error', $validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $user = User::create([
        'firstname' => $request->firstname,
        'lastname'  => $request->lastname,
        'username'  => $request->username,
        'password'  => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('Pramopro')->accessToken;

    return response()->json(['success' => $success, 'message' => 'You have successfully registered'], 200);
}

public function login() {
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => request('username'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('Pramopro')->accessToken;

        return response()->json(['success' => $success, 'message' => 'You have succesfully signed in.'], 200);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

Both API endpoints work fine when tested on Postman.

Following the logic, what would be the best way to set up an API endpoint that will display the authenticated user info?

Answer (score 1):

**For login:**
I suggest that you don't need to send a message back to frontend or devices. Just send the token like the following:

```
{
    "api_token": "kdlksjdflksjdlfkjsdlkfjslkdfjskjflksdjflskdjflskdjlfksjfd"
}
```

You can show a success message if the status is 200 or if the value for api_token is true.

As for **register:**
you just send a message saying success or whatever. If the status is 200 then it's understood that the user is registered.

Comment: I agree with keep messages short or removing all together from the login method. However, the question on how best to set up an api that will be called when redirected to the dashboard still remains. How would you do it?

Comment: From your comment, it seems you are trying to say that you want to **redirect** the user after login or registration to the desired page. Answer: If you are using any frontend library or framework then after checking the status you redirect to a certain page using your frontend library or framework's own code or it's one of the packages. Same goes for android/iOS. **Now** if you are just using a blade template to show frontend stuff then I'm sure you understand that you don't need API in the first place.

Comment: Redirect is done on frontend js code or device's Java or Swift code

Comment: Right, the frontend will do the redirection. What I want to do is have an endpoint that will return the user details so the frontend can display it. Say something like `Route::get('profile', 'BaseController@profile')`, then in the `profile()` method how should it be handled?

Comment: I understand now. After the response from login, you get API token which you store on local storage or cookies using frontend code. Then you redirect to profile(for example). When the profile is loading you do an ajax get call with Bearer token on the header. Your backend will cross check bearer token with the database. If it's matched then profile data will be sent as ajax response. Which you show on the page.

Comment: So the token generated during registration or login needs to be stored in the db?

Comment: Yes. How else are you going to authenticate. When we do regular session authentication we match password. For API authentication we match API key.

Comment: Remember to up vote if you are satisfied with the answer 